# What is the correct way to set up a UnitTest project for C++ in Visual Studio with additional include directories in the main Project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, unit-testing, testing

I am trying to test a C++ Project in Visual Studio 2019.

The project, which should be tested, has a class MyClass. The project folder has a directory "include" and I did set up the path in **Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional include directory**.

MyClass.h:

```
#pragma once

#include <string>

class MyClass
{
public:
    void print() const;
};
```

MyClass.cpp:

```
#include "MyClass.h"

void MyClass::print() const {
    printf("MyClass print"); 
}
```

This code executes just fine.

Now when I try to test this solution with a new UnitTest Project in the same solution I have some problems how to include MyClass and to test it there.

I included the reference to the first project in my UnitTest Project.

**Variant 1 in UnitTest1.cpp:**

```
#include "..\ConsoleApplication1\include\MyClass.h"
#include "..\ConsoleApplication1\MyClass.cpp"
```

Result:
Error C2011 -> "MyClass": class type new definition

Error C2027 -> Use of undefined type "MyClass"

Error C2070 -> "print": Modifiers not allowed on nonmember functions

Error C2079 -> undefined Class "MyClass"

**Variant 2 in UnitTest.cpp:**

```
#include "..\ConsoleApplication1\include\MyClass.h"
```

Result:
Error LNK2019, 1120 unresolved externals

I believe this is because of the additional include directory in the main project. Without additional include directory and with "#include "include\MyClass.h" in MyClass.cpp, the UnitTest works correctly
.
How do i include the Classes from the origninal project into the UnitTest Project properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to also add the same "include" folder from the first project to **Properties > C/C++ > General > Additional include directory** in the *TestUnit Project*.

Then I can add

```
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "..\ConsoleApplication1\MyClass.cpp"
```

to the TestUnit1.cpp file and use the class MyClass correctly.

Answer (score -1):

You have to add MyClass.cpp to the sources for the test project.